# OpenGL shader compile error (C0000 and C0206) (PyOpenGL)

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, glsl, pyopengl

I'm still pretty new to opengl and i'm trying to compile my vertex and fragment shader but keep getting an error. Heres the shaders i'm compiling:

```
# Vertex shader
vert_shader = """
#version 330
in vec4 position
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
}

"""

# Fragment shader
frag_shader = """
#version 330
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

"""

# Compiles the vertex and fragment shader
shader = OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileProgram(OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(str(vert_shader), GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
                                          OpenGL.GL.shaders.compileShader(str(frag_shader), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))
```

When i run my program, i get this error:

```
RuntimeError: ('Shader compile failure (0): b\'0(4) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected reserved word "void", expecting \\\',\\\' or \\\';\\\' at token "void"\\n\'', [b'\n    #version 330\n    in vec4 position\n    void main()\n    {\n        gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);\n    }\n\n    '], GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
```

Initially i thought i was getting this error because i didn't parse the string and take out the new line indicators, but once i took those out using the 'replace' string function, i got this error:

```
RuntimeError: ('Shader compile failure (0): b\'0(1) : error C0205: invalid profile "in"\\n0(1) : error C0206: invalid token "vec4" in version line\\n\'', [b'    #version 330    in vec4 position    void main()    {        gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);    }    '], GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
```

I even tried encoding the string as ascii after parsing it but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: I see a missing semicolon on line 2 of the vertex shader.

Comment: Also `position` is a `vec4` already, so the conversion to a `vec4` by adding a 1.0 at the end does not make sense. You could just use `gl_Position = position;` or make line 2 just `in vec3 position;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vertex shader had syntax errors, try again with this fixed one:

```
#version 330

in vec4 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

1) You were missing ';' in the line `in vec4 position`

2) Line `gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);` was trying to create a vec4 instance with the first argument position, which happens to be a vec4. To fix it you can just assigning directly the vec4 position like `gl_Position = position;` or using [swizzling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling) like `gl_Position = vec4(position.xyz, 1.0);`